# How can I delete the mid edges of the curves in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I create a path and want to instantiate objects along the side parts of the path using `Instance on Points`. However, when I try to do this, all edges are converted to curves and not just the side parts. I would have to delete the middle edges of the curve to make it work the way I want.

This is the path I want to use:

[image]

This is how I am currently trying to solve this:

[image]

Along the curves marked here I want to instantiate the objects:

[image]

That is the result I am currently achieving:

[image]

Download [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14MfhhqnTTlY1AdhC3vhPDsHkAPecDD0p/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I don't get the question ....where do you instantiate something and what is the result you don't want to have? The node `Distribute Points on Faces` distributes the points namely: to faces...

Comment: Please check the file I have uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OK, your question was a little confusing and the pictures honestly couldn't explain what your goal is.

But here is the solution:

[image]
[image]

Subdivide the *Curve Line* before you convert it into a mesh. Then mark the start point and the end point, so you can select the edges afterwards.

Then convert your curves with `Curve to Mesh`.

Since you marked the endpoints before, you can now use them as selection for `Mesh to Curve`, and remain: The side parts of your road as single curves.

You can then instantiate your objects on these as you wish.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, and I am sorry for my question that I couldn't explain you. I was really wondering this.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, and I am sorry for my question that I couldn't explain you. I was really wondering this.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, and I am sorry for my question that I couldn't explain you. I was really wondering this.